# Custom webpart behaves differently with different environment?

Tags: web-part, list

I have a custom solution which retrieves all the list items from the list with 12000 items. I have used splistitemcollection position method to get listitems to retrieve list items. It works fine in Dev environment, But when i am deploying it in Test environment. Sharepoint throws list view threshold error.

My code is looks exactly as the below link provided by (Vedran Rasol)
[Server timeout issue when getting 500000 records from SharePoint 2010 list](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/20492/server-timeout-issue-when-getting-500000-records-from-sharepoint-2010-list).

Answer (score 1):

The error tells you that you have reached threshold limit imposed for your site collection in Test environment. To manage this you should

1. Manually change your settings in Central Administration
2. Or override this with API. Be sure that in CA your "Allow object model override" option is set to yes

See [this](http://norpoint.wordpress.com/2012/07/12/change-or-disable-throttling-settings-for-large-sharepoint-lists/) to see how.

In the link you have specified there were already article mantioned how to manage this: http://www.sharepointjoel.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=241

Hope it helps,

Andrew