# Request timeout error large list SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, large-lists

I have one custom list which contains appox 10500000 data and it was working fine. but after that it throws timeout error.

so what we did is we trim 20 Lakhs data from that list so list has now 8000000 items. but still it throws timeout error previously it was working with 10000000 data also.

List threshold value is 11000000.
Current items in list is 8000000.

we are trying to retrieving data using C# code. Below is the code

```
SPList list = web.Lists[listName];
SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
query.Query = "<Where><And><In><FieldRef Name='Site' LookupId='TRUE' /><Values><Value Type='Integer'>95</Value><Value Type='Integer'>178</Value><Value Type='Integer'>129</Value><Value Type='Integer'>208</Value><Value Type='Integer'>72</Value><Value Type='Integer'>75</Value><Value Type='Integer'>131</Value><Value Type='Integer'>39</Value><Value Type='Integer'>96</Value><Value Type='Integer'>479</Value><Value Type='Integer'>86</Value><Value Type='Integer'>67</Value><Value Type='Integer'>125</Value><Value Type='Integer'>23</Value><Value Type='Integer'>165</Value><Value Type='Integer'>472</Value><Value Type='Integer'>132</Value><Value Type='Integer'>118</Value><Value Type='Integer'>70</Value><Value Type='Integer'>79</Value><Value Type='Integer'>108</Value><Value Type='Integer'>40</Value><Value Type='Integer'>666</Value><Value Type='Integer'>158</Value><Value Type='Integer'>94</Value><Value Type='Integer'>227</Value><Value Type='Integer'>101</Value><Value Type='Integer'>474</Value><Value Type='Integer'>42</Value><Value Type='Integer'>63</Value><Value Type='Integer'>102</Value></Values></In><Gt><FieldRef Name='Resulted_x0020_Date_x0020_Time' /><Value Type='DateTime'>2017-06-17T19:00:00Z</Value></Gt></And></Where><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Resulted_x0020_Date_x0020_Time' Ascending='False' /></OrderBy>";
query.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name=\"ID\"/><FieldRef Name=\"FirstName\"/><FieldRef Name=\"Last_x0020_Name\"/><FieldRef Name=\"Birthday\"/><FieldRef Name=\"Gender\"/><FieldRef Name=\"Resulted Date Time\"/>";
query.RowLimit = 50;
SPListItemCollection myItems = list.GetItems(query);
int count = myItems.Count;
```

Comment: try increasing the row limit. however the data is too large and it shouldnt work in SharePoint

Comment: Already asked here and answered https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/20492/server-timeout-issue-when-getting-500000-records-from-sharepoint-2010-list btw that is a rediculous ammount to return. You should do it in batches based on pages so only load and call what is in view ;)

Comment: tried with pages but same with that also

Comment: did you tried indexing columns?

Comment: yes, but not working

Comment: Perform maintenance on content database and scale up your SQL Server, improve storage IOPS, in the meantime redesign your solution, use multiple containers instead of one list and use search for querying if a short lag is acceptable.

Comment: When you recycle items in a list, they still remain in the database table, they only get a non-zero DeleteTransactionId attribute value, so almost no improvement has been made to SQL backend by trimming.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is on-premises, you can try to increase request timeout in web.config of SharePoint webapplication. Did you tried this?

```
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="360" />
```

Here 360 is seconds. Change this to 15 minutes=900 and check. 
Check [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/DennisBottjer/archive/2009/04/13/increase-sharepoint-execution-timeout.aspx) more about web.config.